# Title in org agenda block view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is it possible to set a title for a block in multi-command agenda view? I currently see this:

```
... normal agenda view here
========================================================================================
Headlines with TAGS match: -SCHEDULED={.+}-DEADLINE={.+}/-DONE-DEFERRED-CANCELLED
  work:       TODO Some task
```

I'd like to replace the line starting with "Headers with TAGS" with a custom title, eg "Unscheduled tasks".

This is the value of `org-agenda-custom-commands`:

```
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        `(("n" "Agenda and TODOs"
           ((agenda "")
            (tags "-SCHEDULED={.+}-DEADLINE={.+}/-DONE-DEFERRED-CANCELLED")
            (alltodo "")))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found documentation on it from org [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html). Last argument to the agenda command is a list of "settings" for the view/block. There's a setting called `org-agenda-overriding-header` specifically for this. Furthermore there is a some built-in support for my purposes, so the block became this arguably cleaner version:

```
  (alltodo ""
           ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done 'scheduled 'deadline))
           (org-agenda-overriding-header "Unscheduled tasks")))
```